# Determine schedule/lowest isolation level

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to learn about concurrency, I'm using an Oracle database with SQLPlus.

I have two transactions:

Transaction 1:

```
SET ECHO ON
SET VERIFY OFF

SELECT ename, city
FROM EMPLOYER
WHERE state = 'New South Wales';

UPDATE POSITION
SET bonus = salary / 10
WHERE salary > 100000;

COMMIT;
```

Transaction 2:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
SET ECHO ON

ACCEPT AdditionBonus NUMBER PROMPT 'Addition Bonus>'

UPDATE POSITION
SET bonus = NVL(bonus, 0) + &AdditionBonus
WHERE pnumber < 00000007;

UPDATE POSITION
SET salary = salary + 1000
WHERE salary < 400000;

COMMIT;
```

I'm trying to determine whether I can run these in READ COMMITTED or if it has to be SERIALIZABLE. I'm also trying to write down the possible schedules for these transactions being run concurrently but it's doing my head in. So far the other similar questions on SE haven't really clarified the issue for me.

How would I go about determining the schedules for these transactions in both modes?

EDIT: Rows from `POSITION`

```
   PNUMBER     SALARY      BONUS
---------- ---------- ----------
     1      45000
     2     450000      45000
     3      50000
     4     200000      20000
     5     200000      20000
     6     100000
     7     800000      80000
     8      45000     100000
     9     450000      45000
    10      50000
```

Comment: Simply start two interactive SQLPLUS sessions, do the first update in the first session without commit, then do the second update in the second session without commit too, then commit the transaction in the first session, then commit in the second session. Finally do a select from table and you will see an outcome.

Comment: I get that, but I'm trying to get a deeper understanding then what a test like that provides

Comment: It's not at all clear what the test is meant to show. What has the `EMPLOYER` query got to do with it? Do any positions have salary > 100000 and < 400000, and of those, do any have pnumber < 7?

Comment: Hi William, it's just meant as an exercise to learn about concurrency. I've updated my question with the row data so hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: The outcomes in both modes (read commited/serializable) will be exactly the same if you run both transactions in the same order. I do not really know what result you want to get and what you would not like it to be.